# "He leaned into the window to kiss her" and "to climb out of / into the window to get “out of" or “into" the house?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

There is a man **inside** a room on the 2nd floor. Is it idiomatic to say the following?

> "Don't **lean out** of the window. You may fall out."

Now, there is a man standing **outside** a house at the window. His girlfriend is inside the house. Can we say

> "He **leaned into** the window to kiss her."

because the opposite of "**out of**" is "**into**"?

Also, can we say

- "*We climbed **out of** the window to get out of the house.*" and
  "*We climbed **into** the window to get into the house*"?

or do we have to say

- "*We climbed **through** the window **to get out** of the house*" and
  "*We climbed **through** the window **to get into** the house*"?

Comment: *He leaned **through** the window to kiss her.* Generally speaking, you lean ***into*** some "containing space" (such as a room or car), but ***through*** an opening (a window or doorway).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica, but some people say "don't lean out of the window as you may fall"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly you can speak of climbing out of a window.

I think it would be more idiomatic to say 'climb' or 'lean *in through* a window'. We speak of a bird *flying into* a window when it crashes into the glass because it doesn't understand about windows.

Comment: If the window was already opened, to "lean into" or "lean through" would also be fine.

Comment: English prepositions are tricky. So, we can say "he learned out of the window" but not "he leaned into the window" meaning "his head got through the window", can't we?

Comment: It's not _wrong_ to say 'leaned into the window', but the consensus seems to be that 'in through' or 'in at the window' are more idiomatic.